# Non-blocking read from sys.stdin

Tags: python, io

I am trying to read from `sys.stdin` while also reading from other network sockets with the following code:

```
import sys
import select

input = [sys.stdin]

inputready, outputready, exceptionready = select.select(input, [],[])
for s in inputready:
    if inputready == sys.stdin:
        data = sys.stdin.readline()
        print(data)
```

My problem is that `inputready` never equals `sys.stdin` which is what I expect. What am I missing?

Comment: select.select() always return a list. Obviously, a list never equals to stdin.

Comment: Edited to take care of a list. I already did that in the original code but still doesn't work.

Comment: Ooh, you were right, am still comparing the list to sys.stdin.I fixed it